# Is it possible to customize WHOIS response for .health domains?

Tags: domains, whois

I have a domain name registered under the [.health TLD](https://icannwiki.org/.health), but when I look up the domain using `whois` I don't see my name appear as the Registrant or Technical contact. Instead, I see this generic response that seems to be the same for other .health domains I looked at.

```
contact:      administrative
name:         Eric Brown
organisation: DotHealth LLC
address:      120 SW 8th St Miami, FL 33131
address:      United States
phone:        +1-305-372-0075
fax-no:       +1-305-372-0076
e-mail:       admin@dothealth.co

contact:      technical
name:         Director
organisation: Neustar, Inc.
address:      21575 Ridgetop Circle
address:      Sterling, VA 20166
address:      United States
phone:        +1 844-677-2878
fax-no:       +1 571-434-5401
e-mail:       technical1@registry.neustar
```

I have already logged into my Registrar's web console (Name.com) to confirm that whois privacy is **disabled** (and has been that way for more than 2 weeks) but I still don't see my information appear in whois.

Is there any way to customize or change our whois response for a `.health` TLD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving the concerned name, and in all cases you should first discuss with your registrar.

As for the generic question "Is it possible to customize WHOIS response for .health domains?" or for any gTLD in fact, the answer is no in the sense that the format and content is mandated by ICANN rules.

What is put inside, specifically contact data, will depend on both the registry and the registrar. There is an ICANN temporary specification, that has to deal with GDPR.

**BUT** I think you are looking at the wrong whois anyway. What you seem to show above is the result of whois for `.health` if you search at the IANA whois server, that is you are showing whois data for the TLD, not for a domain under the TLD.

```
$ whois -h whois.iana.org health
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

domain:       HEALTH

organisation: DotHealth, LLC
address:      120 SW 8th St Miami FL 33131
address:      United States

contact:      administrative
name:         Eric Brown
organisation: DotHealth LLC
address:      120 SW 8th St Miami, FL 33131
address:      United States
phone:        +1-305-372-0075
fax-no:       +1-305-372-0076
e-mail:       admin@dothealth.co

contact:      technical
name:         Director
organisation: Neustar, Inc.
address:      21575 Ridgetop Circle
address:      Sterling, VA 20166
address:      United States
phone:        +1 844-677-2878
fax-no:       +1 571-434-5401
e-mail:       technical1@registry.neustar
```

This is **NOT** what you should do get data on your domain name under `.health`!
For that you need to use the TLD whois server, which is shown in fact below in the response above that I cut:

```
status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://www.dothealth.co
```

So this registry in fact has no whois server which is strange for a gTLD, certainly an edge case against everything I know about ICANN regulations. The only way to get data on your domain is to go to above page. It will certainly not show the same thing than what you quoted.

If you go to registry website you have a link to their web whois: https://whois.nic.health/

And in fact they have a command line whois, as expected and mandated by ICANN it is just that IANA data does not seem up to date.
You can try yourself:

```
$ whois -h whois.nic.health whatis.health
Domain Name: whatis.health
Registry Domain ID: DFC7F15B68DA44DA39BF63EECC792ACF2-NSR
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.godaddy.com
Registrar URL: whois.godaddy.com
Updated Date: 2019-04-20T15:25:26Z
Creation Date: 2019-04-15T15:25:25Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2020-04-15T15:25:25Z
Registrar: GoDaddy.com, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 146
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@godaddy.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.4806242505
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name:
Registrant Organization: What Is Health
Registrant Street:
Registrant Street:
Registrant Street:
Registrant City:
Registrant State/Province: New Jersey
Registrant Postal Code:
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone:
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax:
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name:
Admin Organization:
Admin Street:
Admin Street:
Admin Street:
Admin City:
Admin State/Province:
Admin Postal Code:
Admin Country:
Admin Phone:
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax:
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name:
Tech Organization:
Tech Street:
Tech Street:
Tech Street:
Tech City:
Tech State/Province:
Tech Postal Code:
Tech Country:
Tech Phone:
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax:
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Name Server: ns07.domaincontrol.com
Name Server: ns08.domaincontrol.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2020-04-03T21:53:39Z <<<
```

As for

> to confirm that whois privacy is disabled

even so, the registry (and registrar) are forced not to show all personal data per ICANN regulations. It depends on a lot of things, where you (ie the registrant) are located (EU or not), etc.

Comment: I think you completely answered my question by saying that ICANN prohibits showing personal data in some cases. Thanks.